# Can't use external C++ libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries

I've been fighting with this for hours today - trying to run some simple code from a MatPlot++ library. The code is copied and pasted straight from their website. Every time I try to run the code (using VS community 2019) I get a series of errors:

```
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "matplot/matplot.h"
Error (active)  E0725   name must be a namespace name   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "pareto" is undefined
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "title" is undefined 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "show" is undefined
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'matplot/matplot.h': No such file or directory
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>
#include <random>

int main() {
    using namespace matplot;

    std::vector<double> codelines = { 200, 120, 555, 608, 1024, 101, 57, 687 };
    std::vector<std::string> coders = { "Fred",  "Ginger", "Norman", "Max",
                                       "Julia", "Wally",  "Heidi",  "Pat" };

    pareto(codelines, coders);
    title("Lines of Code by Programmer");

    show();
    return 0;
}
```

I've installed the library using the exe installer, I've downloaded the source files and added their directory to the additional include directories. I've put the files inside the project directory, tried several variations of `#include` using different filepaths. Nothing is working.

The closest I've got is putting the library files into the project folder and changing it to use `""` instead of `<>`. This got rid of the errors for the main `matplot.h` header file, but then it created errors saying that every single dependency was also missing, despite them all being within the same directory.

Please can someone help point out what I could be doing wrong here? I'm not used to using external libraries so its driving me crazy.

Comment: You need to add the directory containing the `matplot` dir with the headers as include directory. Probably there's a dir named `include` somewhere in your installation. All the other errors are probably just the result of the missing include. You should find the settings to adjust via project properties for your target -> `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`

Comment: Just tried that using the installed location of matplot. Tried pointing it to the include folder's parent, and the folder itself. Still nothing. Could it be related to permissions? Its a work laptop so sometimes admin permissions get in the way

Comment: Just reading is usually you do have read permissions and lacking read permissions would be the only thing preventing the compiler from using a header. There could potentially be an issue with you setting the include dir only for one configuration, but trying to build another. The way you can determine the correct directory to use as include directory is 1. find the `matplot.h` header and open the dir in Windows explorer. 2. double check, that the directory containing this header is named `matplot`. 3. Navigate 1 dir up. 4. copy the path of this the current directory to the VS properties.

Comment: In step 4. you should make sure the combo boxes show `All Platforms`/`All Configurations` when adding the dir. If you've got the suspicion of unsuitable permissions, you can simply open `matplot.h` in a text editor; If this works, there are no issues with permissions. Btw: In case of the description of the dir to use is unclear, here's an example: Let's say the absolute path to `matplot.h` is `C:\Program Files\matplot\include\matplot\matplot.h` then the directory that needs to be added as additional include dir is `C:\Program Files\matplot\include`

Comment: For how to add file directories, I suggest you read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-170) and use absolute paths.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?